# jQuery, WordPress - Click button id to show sidebar but also scroll to it

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

Firstly, thank you in advance for supporting my question.

I believe the outcome will be straight-forward; but I have a WordPress button with id "**sidebar-toggle**" and its represented as an icon with css. When this button is clicked, a sidebar appears, and when clicked again (to close) the sidebar hides.

However, this is my index.php page which shows latest posts. So when the sidebar appears, it appears all the way down the page, underneath the latest posts.

How would you best ultilise jQuery to successfully scroll down to the sidebar div when the button is clicked?

**CSS**

```
<button id="sidebar-toggle" class="sidebar-toggle"></button>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="sidebar" class="sidebar"> 
<div id="sidebar-inner" class="sidebar-inner">
// all inner content e.g. text is here
</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery("#sidebar-toggle").live("click", function(event){
jQuery('html,body').animate({ scrollTop:$('#sidebar').offset().top});
// the sidebar doesn't appear until clicked - problem when scrolling?
});
});
```

**EDITED JQUERY**

```
        jQuery(function() {
   jQuery("#sidebar-toggle").on( "click", function() { //Click

        if (jQuery("#sidebar").is(":visible")) { //Check to see if element is visible then scroll to it
            jQuery('html,body').animate({ //animate the scroll
                scrollTop: $('#sidebar').offset().top 
            }, "slow")
        }
    });
  return false; //This works similarly to event.preventDefault(); as it stops the default link behavior
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have created a simle example of how it should work. Hope it will
>   help you :)

```js
$(function() {
    $( "#sidebar-toggle" ).on( "click", function() { //Click
   $( "#sidebar" ).slideToggle( "slow", function(){
   if ($(this).is(":visible")) { //Check to see if element is visible then scroll to it
    $('html,body').animate({ //animate the scroll
     scrollTop: $(this).offset().top 
    }, "slow")
   }
  });
   return false; //This works similarly to event.preventDefault(); as it stops the default link behavior
 });
});
```

```css
.sidebar{ margin-top:500px; height:500px; width:200px; background:red;display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="sidebar-toggle" class="sidebar-toggle">toggler</button>

<div id="sidebar" class="sidebar"> 
<div id="sidebar-inner" class="sidebar-inner">
// all inner content e.g. text is here
</div>
</div>
```

To check only if statement:

```
   jQuery(function() {
    if (jQuery('#sidebar').is(":visible")) { //Check to see if element is visible then scroll to it
                    jQuery('html,body').animate({ //animate the scroll
                        scrollTop: jQuery('#sidebar').offset().top 
                    }, "slow")
                }
)};
```

Comment: Great @Sahil Dhir ! But, when this button is clicked, the WordPress theme I'm using already controls this visibility of the sidebar. So, I'm hoping just to make the scrollTop work so it goes straight to the sidebar div. Any thoughts?

Comment: Could we change the jQuery so it checks #sidebar has appeared (controlled by Wordpress theme) then do the rest as you indicated?

Comment: then just call the if statement ,dont use rest of the code.. the if condition will check if the side bar is visible it will scroll to that.. check the updated answer

Comment: Could you please see my amended JQuery in my original question please? I've just tried this however, the animation does not work so far.

Comment: your jquery code is wrong.. Did you tried only my above code?  jQuery(function() {
    if (jQuery('#sidebar').is(":visible")) { //Check to see if element is visible then scroll to it
                    jQuery('html,body').animate({ //animate the scroll
                        scrollTop: jQuery('#sidebar').offset().top 
                    }, "slow")
                }
)};

Comment: Unfortunately the jQuery code given (thank you for that, that made sense just to check its visibility) but it does not scroll to sidebar div.